# Отправка по Email письма c html содержимым c#

Tags: c#, html, email, smtp

Пытаюсь отправить письмо на электронную почту, которое в теле содержит таблицу с некоторыми данными, составленную с помощью html тегов, вида

```html
<table>
<tr>
<td>data1</td>
<td>data2</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Устанавливаю свойство IsBodyHtml в true:
message.IsBodyHtml = true;

Отправляю асинхронно, используя метод smtp.SendAsync(message, null);

Ответочка об отправке пришла.

Но письмо на почту не приходит..

P.S. Отправляю просто текст c тегами перехода на новую строку 
 - отправляется без проблем

В чем может быть проблема?

В общем, нашёл проблему. а проблема была в сервисе почтового ящика. Он помечал эти письма как рассылка и складывал в отдельную папку, причем, в папке входящие они не отображаются.

Вопрос закрыт

Comment: `Но письмо на почту не приходит..` в спам попало? Или с ошибкой какой отвалилось?

Comment: @tym32167, в спам не попадает. я это тоже сразу проверял. и ошибку при отправке не ловит. Хотя, сейчас проверил папку отправленные, почему-то там не нашёл ни писем, которые действительно дошли на указанный мейл, ни тех, которые не дошли

Answer (score 0):

Давайте для начала отправим любое письмо.

1. Создайте smtp client. Подключитесь к почтовому серверу.
2. Создайте сообщение.
3. Отправьтесь сообщение.

Я думаю что у вас первоначальные проблемы именно в этих шагах. А html это небольшое преобразование шага 2.

пробуйте задать данные таким образом

```
<html>
<table width="600" style="border:1px solid #333">
  <tr>
    <td align="center">head</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="center">
      body 
      <table align="center" width="300" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border:1px solid #ccc;">
        <tr>
          <td>data1</td>
          <td>data2</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</html>
```

Comment: Я выше в вопросе указал, что письма не в html разметке отправляются отлично

Comment: я изменил ответ попробуйте изменить его таким образом

Comment: В общем, нашёл проблему. а проблема была в сервисе почтового ящика. Он помечал эти письма как рассылка и складывал в отдельную папку, причем, в папке входящие они не отображаются.